# Problems getting iPhone 11 to charge even when using wireless charger

Tags: iphone, charging

Can someone help me to understand why my iPhone 11 won't charge (most of the time, multiple combos of charging methods)?

Sometimes I will get a %6 but then it will stop, sometimes like now (well I just hope I get to finish typing).
It started with just the wired connections but has now also started to affect the wireless as well.
The phone is about 2.5 years old now but I do updates as soon as they are available.
It is not and never has been jailbroken. Bought new, and I am the only owner.
I do not have any third-party anti-virus or malware protection apps.
Of 64 Gb, 29 Gb is used up.

iCloud is basically empty 250 Mb only though I keep being told it's full and I need to buy more storage. I assume that this is just basic greed on behalf of apple and as I know it's false I don't give it much thought.
If there is any other info I can provide to get help with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this could be an issue with your specific wireless charger. Try testing the wireless charger with other phones, or vice versa (test your phone with other chargers, if available).